# Adding a textstyle in the new RTE editor (TYPO3 8.7.1)

Tags: typo3

Is there a possibility to add a textstyle to a marked text?

The following code does not work...

```
RTE.default.contentCSS = fileadmin/templates/css/rte.css
RTE.default.buttons.textstyle.tags.span.allowedClasses := addToList(huge)
RTE.default.proc.allowedClasses := addToList(huge)
```

Comment: this small tutorial could help you
https://typo3worx.eu/2017/02/configure-ckeditor-in-typo3/
I think that there are some examples inside the full.yaml file in EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Full.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. Added all by manual and can't see any changes.
Also tried:

In TsConfig

```
   #RTE.default.preset = hit_custom
    RTE.default.preset = minimal
    RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext.preset = minimal
    #RTE.tt_content.types.textmedia.bodytext.preset = hit_custom 
    RTE.config.tx_news_domain_model_news.bodytext.preset = default
```

in my ext_localconf.php

```
#https://www.thomaskieslich.de/blog/127-typo3-8x-ckeditor-konfigurieren/
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['hit_custom'] = 'EXT:huskytheme/Configuration/RTE/Custom.yaml';
```

Didn't get any changes. Also can't change general full, minimal or default style - all changes have no effect

**Solved:**

after delete full typo3temp folder  `rm -rf typo3temp/*` and create all folder structure via Install tools i get my changes